# How Dangerous is Unity?

Tags: humans, balancing-magic-systems

No, I do *not* mean unity between other people. In one of the stories I came up with, people become "zombies" once an alien substance (Choromis) distributed unknowingly amongst the population is activated. For some reason, the zombies retain their human intellect but act much like pop-culture zombies; aggressive, relentless, intent on infecting or killing non-infected, and use special traits granted by the Choromis within them. The kicker? The Choromis is color-coded.

Unity, in this case, is a special ability unique to zombies with Purple Choromis. The mix of Red Choromis (which affects the body) and Blue Choromis (which affects the mind) **somehow allows certain zombies to force a 'sync' between body and mind, thereby infusing their frame with telekinetic force and enabling greater precision and reaction time.**

**Wait-greater precision?** Precisely. Because the zombie that's unlocked Unity is using telekinetic-or mentally synchronized forces-to move their body, they have greater control over their body and how it moves, part of which is because of the naturally expanded bodily awareness and part of which is because they are literally using telekinesis on their own body.

**But what about the reaction time?** The greatest overall danger to a zombie is headshots, yes? The trouble is, dodging bullets is nearly impossible. The gap between recognizing a gun aimed at oneself and ducking down is often too large for dodging to be feasible. **And this is where Unity shines, because the body and the mind are synced here. There is, effectively, *no gap between the realization and the reaction, they happen at the same time.*** Once again, telekinesis is being used to move the body. There's no neural gap to slow things down. The only real limit is how fast the body can move; in general, a zombie with Unity is using Instinctive Reaction Time (as close to automatic as one can get) instead of Manual Reaction time, if that makes sense.

**So, while this question may seem subjective, it really comes down to how balanced this is. Too strong, and the humans don't stand against this zombie variant, never mind the others. Too weak, and the zombies won't stand a chance. So, is Unity balanced?**

**Specifications:**

1. To put it simply, Unity is balanced if it allows zombies with Purple Choromis (there's Blue, Red, Yellow, Green, and Orange zombies as well, so 1 out of 6 zombies has Purple Choromis) to feasibly challenge armed and trained soldiers (think XCOM games where you can outfit soldiers with guns and grenades but missile raids and whatnot aren't feasible), while also being vulnerable against a sufficiently experienced or skilled soldier.

**TL;DR:** Zombies are balanced if they are like Parshendi soldiers, unbalanced if they are like Shardbearers. If you don't know those terms, I'm really sorry, that's the best example I have and it comes from the Stormlight Chronicles if you want to look them up on The 17th Coppermind.

Please let me know if there are problems and the question needs editing, I appreciate feedback!

Comment: "Feasibly challenge" means what?  2 zombies will beat 4 soldiers in a crowded elevator?  1 soldier can kill 10 zombies that have to charge across 300m of ground with barbed wire obstacles?  Difficult to answer even knowing the weapons each side has available and the tactical situation, totally unanswerable as is.  Suggest cutting the huge swathes of text down to a single well-defined, objective question.

Comment: This question seems all over the place. You're asking is to evaluate the danger of a thing without context. There isn't a standard unit of danger we can use to calculate danger. So without context without a standard reference you're just soliciting opinions to a disjoint question.

Comment: If you play a bit video games, you'll see that the concept of "balanced" is quite personal : One will find Bastifus to be overpowered, one just an annoyance. But most people forget that balancing is as much as about the character's traits than the conditions they are thrown in : objectives and obstacles to said goals (environment, foes...). So while asking if it's balanced induce a seemingly simple yes/no answer, without knowing anything both answers are correct.[...]

Comment: [...] Thus, it's best to ask these kind of questions : What kind of environment will they be the most efficient against X? How likely this strategy choice would work against X in Y environment? How can they beat X in Y environment? Tell in as much details as you can about this X guy and Y environment, it's very important.

Comment: A purely personal take with just one casual read through from me here, so don't take it to heart .. this is all magic, the science in your sci fi is purely for decoration .. so .. as such, everything in it is entirely up to you .. so why not just get on with it and write your story rather than asking us to write it for you?

Comment: Thanks for the comments everyone! I will see if I can edit and later perhaps even reopen the question.

Answer (score 2):

#### Purple Brain

The perk of the Purple Zombie in combat is that it can dodge what it can see, in a nutshell.  However, it does not appear to be wholly psychic and needs to actually perceive the attack in order to dodge it properly.

The obvious solution is to not be seen when you attack.  Attacking from a position of stealth is the most obvious solution -- If they can't see the gun or crossbow fire the shot, then I severely doubt they can dodge a bullet or bolt.  Even less time if they don't hear the shot and only perceive the projectile coming at them at velocity.

Alternatively, attack in tandem.  If what I get is accurate, then their ability to move their body is still bound by the ways those bodies will move.  If they need to dodge left *and* right, then one of the attacks should hit if they are aimed well.  This will not be a tactic any group can do, instead being a specifically trained skill set of certain people.

#### The Danger Zone

However, the question lacks context in terms of the rest of the world around these purple zombies.  Most people are average so I would guess that they are going to be a bigger threat than the person was, but not significantly more given they are still bound by how their body moves.

It is stated that they have human intelligence.  Does that mean that they will pick up a gun and go hunting if that is in their skillset?  If so, then they will be a lot more dangerous for their weapon and lack of morals.  Though the reduced reaction time will add to the danger.

Can these drones make optimal use of their Choromis-given abilities?  I mean, you can telekinetically  move your body and you crave the flesh of the uninfected.  Is there a specific reason why they would not use their powers to attack from above, where people don't expect to be assaulted from?

In short, we can figure out how potentially lethal one type is, but we lack enough context to determine how that ranks in the system.  Plus, each group of these individuals may be different.

#### TL;DR

Probably dangerous individually.  Unknown how dangerous they would be in context of the world given the question as of 01:10 ET on August 9.